# XML Values in Oracle SQL return with WhiteSpace

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I am trying to pull XML out of an Oracle DB and am trying to add spacing between the returned values, but am having some issues:

The XML:

```
<Value>Value1</Value><Value>Value2</Value><Value>Value3</Value>
```

The SQL:

```
SELECT xmltype(test.values).EXTRACT('/Value/text()').getStringVal() AS "Test Values",
FROM test
```

Comes out as `Value1Value2Value3`

It should come out as `Value1 Value2 Value3` (note the spaces)

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: That isn't valid XML; there is no root node, what are the dashes about?

Comment: The dashes I added as Stack Overflow site would hide the XML values due to the <> brackets, please ignore them. It should be just <value>.

Comment: I see, but that doesn't happen in code blocks; once Orion formatted that into a block the dashes could/should have been removed. I've taken them out now.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way (for 11g and above), using xmltable and string-join:

```
with sample_data as (select xmltype('<root><value>Value1</value><value>Value2</value><value>Value3</value></root>') x from dual)
select x.result
from   sample_data sd,
       xmltable('string-join(/root/value, " ")' passing sd.x
                columns result varchar2(4000) path '.') x;

RESULT
--------------------
Value1 Value2 Value3
```